# How to use a value of a key for another value in an XML .config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have the following in a .config file using C# and ASP.NET:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<appSettings>

  <add key="ConnectionString"
    value="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;" />

</appSettings>
```

And I need the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<appSettings>

  <add key="userkey" value="myuser" />
  <add key="passkey" value="mypass" />
  <add key="ConnectionString"
    value="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=[userkey];Password=[passkey];" />

</appSettings>
```

Is this possible? What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Read the values in the code and use a `ConnectionStringBuilder`. Better yet, don't split it up like this (why would you?) and use a proper `<connectionString>`. Encrypted, if possible.

Comment: Agreed, use the ConnectionString block.  It supports NVPs.

Comment: if you want to allow a user to connect from a Textbox for example when they enter username and password, then construct your connection string in the config file to handle 2 parameters for example `User Id ={0}; Password={1};` then when you get the connection string from the config file you create a property that will get the ConnectionString, textbox for user id , textbox for Password this is actually very simple to setup